# Achieving Guaranteed Delivery as a Publisher with MassTransit and ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, masstransit

I am seeing ActiveMQ throughput of 2000 sequential messages per second in my setup, vs. RabbitMQ throughput of 250 sequential messages. What makes RabbitMQ slow are message acknowledgements for senders. This guarantees delivery. The [ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/activemq/advanced-features/async-sends) document talks about this topic as well and notes that

> If you are not using transactions and are sending persistent messages, then each send is synch and blocks until the broker has sent back an acknowledgement to the producer that the message has been safely persisted to disk. This ack provides that guarantee that the message will not be lost but it also costs a huge latency penalty since the client is blocked.

This "huge latency penalty" is what I am expecting but not seeing. The number of 250 roundtrips sound more realistic than 2000. I am suspecting that I am not getting guaranteed delivery with ActiveMQ. I have not been able to artificially get a dropped message.

The [MassTransit code includes nms.AsyncSend = true](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/49dd109930868ce334e9245aaab190c812dab126/src/Transports/MassTransit.ActiveMqTransport/ActiveMqTransport/Configuration/ConfigurationHostSettings.cs#L37). In the context of nms.AsyncSend = true, the article mentions the following:

> Many high performance applications are designed to tolerate a small amount of message loss in failure scenarios. If your application has been designed in this fashion, you can enable the use of async sends to increase throughput even when using persistent messages.

What is the guarantee I'm getting, and how can I get guaranteed delivery?

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you misunderstood the ActiveMQ documentation you cited. It doesn't describe any guarantee you have when you enable async sends.

In short, you *can't* get guaranteed delivery with async sends. That's why the documentation says that async sends for persistent messages are only for applications which "are designed to tolerate a small amount of message loss in failure scenarios." Therefore, you should only enable async sends with persistent messages if "your application has been designed in this fashion."

The only situations where you could send async with any guarantees are:

- When using a transaction you can send all messages async and commit (which is sync) once.
- When using an API like JMS 2 which supports a callback mechanism like the [`CompletionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/CompletionListener.html) you can send async and still be notified if there was a problem sending the message.

In my opinion, turning on async send by default, while good for performance, is bad for reliability and violates the common expectation of most developers when sending persistent messages. This probably won't be noticed by most developers until they encounter real message loss.

If you want guaranteed delivery then set async send to `false`.

Comment: Ultimately the situation is that MassTransit doesn't support non-async sends out of the box and PRs are welcome.

Comment: That's correct. The current value of `true` is hard-coded (i.e. `{ "nms.AsyncSend", "true" }`) in MassTransit. A new flag would be needed to allow it to be configured differently. In the end the only way to get guaranteed sends is to disable async.